# sequelize count does not work with nested objects

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

pInvent.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const PInvent = sequelize.define('prod_invent', {
        id: {primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, unique: true},
        sku_id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        }
    });

    PInvent.associations = (db) => {
        PInvent.belongsToMany(db.cTags, {
            as: 'CTags',
            through: 'c_prod',
            foreignKey: 'prod_id',
            otherKey: 'c_id'
        });
    };

    return PInvent
}
```

pCure.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const PCure = sequelize.define('prod_cure', {
            id: {primaryKey: true, type: DataTypes.INTEGER, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, unique: true},
            c_tag: {type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true}

        });

    PCure.associations = (db) => {
        PCure.belongsToMany(db.pInvent, {
            as: 'CProd',
            through: 'c_prod',
            foreignKey: 'c_id',
            otherKey: 'prod_id'
        });
    };


    return PCure
}
```

db.js

```
db.pInvent = require('../model/pInvent')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.cTags = require('../model/pCure')(sequelize, Sequelize);


db.cTags.associations(db);
```

Now when I write the code as shown below :

```
db.cTags.findAll({
            attributes: ['prod_cure.*', 'prod_invent.*', [Sequelize.fn('COUNT', Sequelize.col('prod_invent.id')), 'PostCount']],
            include: [{
                model: db.pInvent, as: 'CProd'
            }]
        }).then((data) => {
            res.json({info:data})
        }).catch((err) => {
            res.json({errInfo:err})
        })
```

it gives me the error as shown below :

Unknown table 'prod_invent'

What i want here is , i wanted calculate the count of nested object , but i am not able to do.

Comment: Did you checked actual table name inside your database? Make sure table with name `prod_invent` exists. Normally `Sequelize` creates table with plural name, ie, `prod_invents`.

Comment: @이준형 I checked it . but it is the same . there is no issue with table names